# How to mount a Windows' folder in Docker using Powershell (or CMD)?

Tags: powershell, docker

I would like to run a container on Windows 10 and mount my local folder to a folder in the container. Let's take the following command as an example, but any container will do.

```
 docker run -v "$(pwd)":/data -- name mongo -d mongo mongod --smallfiles
```

The issue is with the pwd command. In a Unix environment it returns a relative path, but in Windows it returns an absolute path.

I have tried replacing "$(pwd)" with "." or even "./" with no luck. I also tried `($pwd | Resolve-Path -Relative)`. In all cases I get

```
Error parsing reference: ":/data" is not a valid repository/tag.
```

What works is replacing "$(pwd)" with `/d/path/to/my/folder`.

```
docker run -v /d/path/to/my/folder:/data -- name mongo -d mongo mongod --smallfiles
```

(which is d:\path\to\my\folder) and the mounting is done correctly. However, I'd like to make the command generic, so it can be run from any folder on the host.

Comment: Apparently `"$(pwd)"` is not run as a command, rather it seems to be interpreted as a value of the `pwd` variable (guess as I left Windows world behind long ago). Given that the value is void you are getting the error `":/data" is not a valid repository/tag.` -- notice that there is no directory name ahead of the colon... Switch to linux or OSX...

Comment: Duplicate with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10

Answer (score 18):

This works in PowerShell:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/data alpine ls /data
```

See *[Mount current directory as a volume in Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217)*.

Comment: the simplicity of this makes it the most useful answer to me

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Works in PowerShell 7 Win11 too, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) `/<drive>/<path>` is the correct syntax for mounting folders:

> On Windows, mount directories using:
>
> ```
> docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
> ```

You can make your command more generic by transforming a path to what Docker expects:

```
$PWD.Path -replace '^|\\+','/' -replace ':'
```

like this:

```
docker run -v "$($PWD.Path -replace '^|\\+','/' -replace ':')":/data -- ...
```

If the drive letter must be lowercased (can't test, since I don't have Docker running on Windows) it gets a little more complicated. If you can lowercase the entire string you could replace `$PWD.Path` with `$PWD.Path.ToLower()`. If you must lowercase just the drive letter and preserve case in the rest of the path you could use a callback function:

```
$re = [regex]'^([A-Z]):'
$cb = { $args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToLower() }

docker run -v "$($re.Replace($PWD.Path, $cb) -replace '^|\\+','/')":/data -- ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. I wonder if it is related to the drive letter being capitalized in Windows ? Otherwise, your solution should be correct