# Docker: How to mount current directory in Windows 10

Tags: docker

I am using docker toolbox v17.03 in Windows 10 Home. I am playing with flask app from python slim. I tried to mount the current directory to app and tried ${PWD} and %cd% like below.

```
docker container run -it  -p 5000:5000 -e FLASK_APP=app.py --rm -e FLASK_DEBUG=1 -v %cd%:/app web1
```

==> Got the error saying invalid characters

```
docker container run -it  -p 5000:5000 -e FLASK_APP=app.py --rm -e FLASK_DEBUG=1 -v ${PWD}:/app web1
```

==> Neither error nor working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second form ${PWD} would be [working in a Powershell session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489932/6309).

If it still says "invalid characters", that means:

- the %cd% is not resolved as an absolute path
- it includes characters that are not in `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`, making it inelligible for a volume *name*.

Double-check what %cd% returns, and if there is any special non-ascii character in it (or spaces)