# Docker shared volumes failing refresh with React

Tags: reactjs, docker, windows-10-universal

On Win10/HyperV (not Toolbox), simple file sharing across volumes works fine, similar to this **[Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7K11G0SypJQ)**.

However, when trying to set up volume sharing for a React dev environment, following **[Zach Silveira’s example](https://zach.codes/frontend-development-with-docker/)** to the letter, the volume sharing no longer seems to work.

```
    c:> mkdir docker-test 
    c:> cd docker-test
    # CRA here

    # build the container here
    c:\docker-test> docker build -t test-app .

    # Run docker with the volume map
    c:\docker-test> docker run --rm -it -v $pwd/src:/src -p 3000:3000 test-app

    # load localhost:3000
    # make a change to App.js and look for change in the browser
```

Changes in App.js DO NOT reflect in the browser window.

I’ve heard this worked with toolbox, but there may be issues with the new Win10 HyperV Docker. What’s the secret?

Answer (score 1):

[Zach Silveira’s example](https://zach.codes/frontend-development-with-docker/) is done on a Mac, where `$(pwd)` would mean "current folder.

On a Windows shell, try for testing to replace `$pwd` with `C:/path/to/folder`

As mentioned in "[Mount current directory as volume in Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489151/6309)":

- `%cd%` could work
- `${PWD}` works in a *Powershell* session.