# How to actually bind mount a file in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm attempting to update the [sebp/elk](https://store.docker.com/community/images/sebp/elk/dockerfile) Logstash configuration following [the documentation](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker/blob/master/docs/index.md#updating-logstash-configuration) here. I'm running into a situation in which the host file that I am attempting to mount is being mounted as a directory in the container.

I found this related question [How to mount a single file in a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume) but the notion of running with PWD didn't work for me on Windows as I got the following error:
`C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format`

I'm running Docker on Windows 10 (Build 16299.192)

```
λ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:22:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:28:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

My Docker run command is:

`docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 5044:5044 -it -v d:/docker/elk/logstash-snmp.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-snmp.conf --rm --name elk sebp/elk`

I've been able to run other containers with persistent storage out of this disk (SQL Server, Redis, Exist-DB), but I'm not sure if I'm missing something on this. How can I tell Docker to actually mount this as a file and not as a directory.

Comment: Just make a folder for logstash and mount it at `conf.d`... Logstash actually *expects* a folder of all configurations

Comment: Also, PWD should work in powershell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

**Note**: This approach addresses W10 Home Edition with Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox.

**Overview**: Create a folder in local-machine, mount this as a shared folder in Docker VM, use this shared folder as a bindmount to Docker container.

1. Stop docker VM using `docker-machine stop default`
2. Open VirtualBox, find `default` go to `Settings > Shared Folder`
3. You will see `c/Users` is binded to your `c:\Users`
4. Add a new shared folder, note the name it is assigned. Let's name this as [local-shared]
5. Exit `Settings`
6. `docker-machine start default`
7. Once started, `docker-machine ssh default`
8. `sudo vi /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`
9. Append the following:

   ```
     # create a directory in VM
     mkdir /home/docker/[foldername]
     # mount/map shared folder on localmachine to directory
     sudo moun -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 [local-shared] /home/docker/[foldername]
   ```
10. Save and exit ssh.
11. `docker-machine stop default`
12. `docker-machine start default` (or perhaps `docker-machine restart default`)
13. now `docker container run -d -p 1234:6789 -v /[local-shared]/sub-dir:/[container-dir] dockerImage2Run`

And it should work.

Ref: http://support.divio.com/local-development/docker/how-to-use-a-directory-outside-cusers-with-docker-toolbox-on-windowsdocker-for-windows

Comment: Good steps. Step-13 needs correction, Instead of [local-shared], it should be /home/docker/[foldername]

Answer (score 8):

If you are on windows, there is a problem in mapping the paths. I am using Git bash terminal on windows and the command which works for me is in this format.

1. To copy a file named runtime_config.yml from host to container. The host path is given relative by using PWD as below. And the container path is from root.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v "/${PWD}/etc/runtime_config.yml":/demand_forecast/etc/runtime_config.yml ....
```

2. To copy a directory named etc from host to container. The host path is given relative by using PWD as below. And the container path is from root.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v "/${PWD}/etc/":/demand_forecast/etc/ ....
```

Notice the / at the beginning in host path, that is very important, otherwise you will run into errors.

Comment: if someone wants to run the same on Powershell
docker run -p 9090:9090 -v "$(pwd)/test.yml:/etc/test/test.yml" <image>

Comment: Upvoted for the "Notice the / at the beginning in host path". I'm using Git Bash and I was having strange path errors until I figured out Git Bash modifies the paths in the command line, but "double slash" at the beginning of the path avoids this behavior.