# docker does not create files

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, opencv, aws-lambda

I am new to Docker.

I want to upload cv2 to a AWS lambda function, so I was following https://itnext.io/create-a-highly-scalable-image-processing-service-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-in-10-minutes-7cbb2893a479

I am trying to generate a Lambda-ready Python package for OpenCV by running

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/package tiivik/lambdazipper opencv-python
```

which is, I assume, supposed to create **opencv-python.zip**  in the current working directory. So that I can upload it to the lambda layer.

But, when I run the command, downloading/pulling happens, but it does not create anything. I have tried other similar tutorials but none of them creates anything.

What's wrong with this?

I have Windows 10 Pro. So, I have Docker Desktop and I am using WSL 2

Comment: The command works and creates `opencv-python.zip` as expected. I tried that on linux. Thus maybe its your windows setup fault?

Comment: @Marcin I am completely new to Docker, what do you think might be in my windows setup that causes this?

Comment: Don't know. Try running with `  -D, --debug ` flag. Maybe you can get some error or info on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if `$(pwd)` is correctly interpreted by the docker command in your current Windows 10 shell session.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489151/6309), from a regular CMD session, try instead:

```
docker run --rm -v  %cd%:/package tiivik/lambdazipper opencv-python
```

In a WSL2 bash session, try also

```
docker run --rm -v  $PWD:/package tiivik/lambdazipper opencv-python
```

Although [read this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/b9l32e/my_experience_with_docker_and_wsl_and_volumes/): as mentioned in "[Setting Up Docker for Windows and WSL to Work Flawlessly](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)", you might need to modify your `wsl.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

# Now make it look like this and save the file when you're done:
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

This is:

- [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)
- with a [`--rm` cleanup option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) in order to delete the transient container
- and a [`-v` volume option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#tmpfs-mount-tmpfs-filesystems) in order to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a file or directory on the host machine into a container.
- and a parameter passed to the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) defined by the  [`tiivik/lambdazipper` Dockerfile](https://github.com/tiivik/LambdaZipper/blob/d7bc8a229b3e5ba33932bc267a31eb7c47ee31fc/Dockerfile#L13), which is the [`package.sh`](https://github.com/tiivik/LambdaZipper/blob/master/package.sh)

Advantage: you don't have to install on your Windows python3 (needed by the `package.sh` script). All the execution environment and its dependencies are already installed in the [`tiivik/lambdazipper`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiivik/lambdazipper) [image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#docker-objects).

Comment: Thank you it works with a regular CMD session. but now I have to figure out why it wont work on my WSL 2 Thankss!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you don't mind, can you break down the command? I am trying to learn Docker. What does each keyword mean?

Comment: @pizza No problem. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @pizza I have further edited the answer with WSL2 clues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation! I tried it but I still could not get the zip file created in a WSL2 session. I also downgraded it to WSL1 as the instructions you linked assume WSL1. I followed every single step, including the wsl.conf part. But, the problem persists. What do you think might be the problem? What else can I try?  Also, In both commands you wrote, what do %cd%:/package and $PWD:/package mean? all I know PWD is my current working directory

Comment: @pizza %cd% is for a Windows CMD session, and represents the current folder. Check what $PWD represents in your WSL2 bash session (`echo $PWD`)

Comment: ```echo $PWD``` displays my current directory

Comment: Yeah it downloads stuff but does not create the zip file. Weird :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210569/discussion-between-vonc-and-pizza).