# How to mount nginx docker's /etc/nginx/ directory to host virtual machine?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, volume, mount

I got this task at the university to run an nginx docker on the virtual machine and mount the /etc/nginx/ directory to the 'pwd'/webconfig, but I don't know how to solve. I tried this:

> docker run -p 80:80 -v 'pwd'/webconfig/:/etc/nginx/ --name websrv -d nginx

but I got this error message at the docker logs

> [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

After this I tried to mount the nginx.conf too:

> docker run -p 80:80 -v 'pwd'/webconfig/nginx.conf/:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf/ -v 'pwd'/webconfig/:/etc/nginx/ --name websrv -d nginx

And then I got this error message in the logs:

> [crit] 1#1: pread() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
>   nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)

This is the point where I cannot step forward.

Comment: I see you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use the right folder to take the nginx.conf file from.

'pwd' usually refers to the current directory. If you run `pwd` in your terminal you will see the current folder you are in.
take that folder and add the /webconfig to get your complete current directory. You'll probably get something like `/usr/username/home/webconfig/`

You can use that folder to mount your docker volumes, and your command should become something like this:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v '/usr/username/home/webconfig/:/etc/nginx/ --name websrv -d nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD/webconfig:/etc/nginx/ --name websrv -d nginx
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `VOLUME` command to mount a volume from host system to docker container. Apart from that you also have `COPY` command to upload a already created config file.

Comment: The `VOLUME` directive doesn't specify anything about host-system content.  There's rarely a reason to use it at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze actually I thought user wanted to mount an entire directory to container from host system. Docker documentation has assembled this scenario nicely  https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mount/