# docker mount on windows, strage characters on the host path

Tags: docker, git-bash, working-directory

from a GitBash console on windows

```
docker run \
    --name testneo4j \
    -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
    -d \
    -v $PWD/neo4j/data:/data \
    -v $PWD/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    -v $PWD/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import\
    -v $PWD/neo4j/plugins:/plugins \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password \
neo4j:latest
```

it creates and mounts on the host folders with stange characters (and doesn't persist container's data as well)

```
c:/test/neo4j/data;C
c:/test/neo4j/logs;C
c:/test/neo4j/import;C
c:/test/neo4j/plugin;C
```

It has the same behavior if i specify the absolute path in this way  `-v /c/test/neo4j/data:/data`

but in this other way it works!    `-v c:/test/neo4j/data:/data`

how can i use the $PWD current directory on windows?

Comment: Have a looksie here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489151/553663