# How to pass a command to a docker container with PowerShell?

Tags: docker, powershell

I would like to send a command to an already existing docker container.

I am forced to do it via powershell or CMD, git bash not giving the correct Windows path using `pwd`.

## Functionnal example

```
$cur_path = $pwd.Path

$container_id = docker run -it -d --volume $cur_path\:/matmuttools saagie/python:3.5.2-1.3.1-centos

docker exec $container_id 'ls'

docker stop $container_id

docker rm $container_id
```

Gives the following output:

```
anaconda-post.log
bin
dev
etc
git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar
home
lib
lib64
lost+found
matmuttools
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

## Non functionnal example

However, when doing something more "complex", docker throws an error:

```
$cur_path = $pwd.Path

$container_id = docker run -it -d --volume $cur_path\:/matmuttools saagie/python:3.5.2-1.3.1-centos

docker exec $container_id 'ls /matmuttools'

docker stop $container_id

docker rm $container_id
```

Throws the following error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting
> container process caused: exec: "ls /matmuttools": stat ls
> /matmuttools: no such file or directory: unknown

If I pass `ls` without quotes and without more argument (just `ls`), it runs in the container. If I pass ls without quotes and with arguments, it runs on the host.

Runs in the container:

```
docker exec $container_id ls
```

Runs on the host:

```
docker exec $container_id ls /
```

How do I properly send a command to execute to a docker container in powershell (or with CMD) ?

Comment: tried `' -c ls /matmuttools '`?

Comment: @LeiYang ``OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: " -c ls /matmuttools ": stat  -c ls /matmuttools : no such file 
or directory: unknown``

Comment: why you insist powershell? normally we use `docker exec -it -- bash`, and i don't see `-- bash` in your command. i think you can try using WSL.

Comment: @LeiYang I need powershell because I need the current context path to create the volume. Git bash does not return the actual windows path, there is a layer in between. Moreover, I do not have WSL available. Finally, what do you mean by ``-- bash`` ?

Comment: I think you execute ls on a different folder rather than /. Try to execute `ls matmuttools`

Comment: Not sure if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489151/13642249) helps out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git bash, to get the actual windows path, use:

```
pwd -W
```

Now that I do not need powershell anymore (I am pretty sure it was not a blocking thing, but anyway):

```
docker exec -it frosty_lamport bash -c "cd /matmuttools; ls"
```