# Docker PHP CLI Output File

Tags: php, docker

New to Docker, I have written a code that reads a CSV file and converts it into JSON. It is working fine.

I follow the below procedure and get a PHP CLI image from the link
https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Follow the instructions it shows me the "Completed" which is output from a file, but how can I get the generated file. Where the file will be?

Code for DockerFile

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
COPY . /challenge
WORKDIR challenge
CMD [ "php", "code.php" ]
```

Code for code.php

```
$file = fopen("./input/source.csv", 'r');
$json = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file,"1024",",")) {
        array_push($json,$row);
    }
fclose($file);
file_put_contents("./output/json/target.json", json_encode($json)); 
echo "Completed";
```

My operating system is Windows.

Comment: you need to mont if you want to see the results

Comment: Can you explain more about it in detail?

Comment: yes preparing a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the docker files `COPY` only copy the files ones at build, you need to mount the files in runtime if you want docker to write back to your folder in your window machine. (the script write the files in your docker, but you will never see it, as docker files are not preserved)

so instead you can use the original image, and mount your folder

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "php", "code.php" ]
```

step 1.
`docker build -t "php-code" .`

step 2.
`docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/:/app php-code` this works in powershell see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489151/12239849) what to use on other systems

[see more about volume mounting](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

PS make sure the folder exists in your working directory or add code to PHP to make the folders