# Why have I an error message "invalid reference format" when working with Docker?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, nginx

I'm following the below tutorial and they use docker. I got an error When I tried to mount my local folder to the container.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhBSlnQcq2k

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

I got the following error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
```

I am using Windows 10 PowerShell, Visual Studio Code, and Nginx image. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: `pwd` doesn't work the same in powershell. Try `-v "$pwd":...` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with powershell you should use `${PWD}` instead of `$(pwd)`

then you should do

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v ${PWD}:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

*possible duplicate of : [Mount current directory as a volume in Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10)*

Comment: Thank you very much. It works 

Comment: Your welcome ! Glad that I was able to help you.