# `$PATH: unknown` error when mounting the current directory in Docker

Tags: docker

I want to use Docker to manage multiple Python versions (I recently got a Mac with Apple Silicon and I use old Python environment).

Since I need to read Python scripts on Docker and save the output files (for later use outside the Docker environment), I tried to mount a folder (on my Mac) following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10).

However, it shows this error:

```
$ docker run --name dpython -it python-docker -v $(pwd):/tmp  /bin/bash

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

It works without `-v $(pwd):/tmp`. I tried to specify different folders such as `~/` and `/Users/` but they didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to replace $(pwd) by ${PWD}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the volume before the image name:

```
$ docker run --name dpython -it -v $(pwd):/tmp python-docker /bin/bash
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks @Paolo! If you know the answer--why does the order matter?

Comment: @user2978524 Because that's how docker works. All flags are specified before the docker image name