# Docker - Jenkins - Local System Files/Folders Access and Execution in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, cypress, docker-desktop

How to access and execute local system folders/files in jenkins when jenkins image is installed in docker desktop container?

**Please help me to find a way by which we can access and execute local files/folders, inside jenkins image available in docker desktop container?**

For example: How to access and run cypress project with jenkins, when the cypress project is available in our local system : For this I've tried by providing custom workspace directory path but also I am getting below errors and not able to run it via jenkins.

- I've also observed that while providing path to custom workspace directory If I use 'Users/...' (i.e not used forward slash at starting) then I am getting below error:

SC Ref. 1: [Custom Workspace path without forward slash at starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxMux.png)

[Console output error for Custom Workspace path without forward slash at starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J5oF.png))

- But while providing path to custom workspace directory If I use '/Users/...' (i.e used forward slash at starting) then I am getting below error:

SC Ref. 2:
[Custom Workspace path with forward slash at starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMoUa.png)

[Console output error for Custom Workspace path with forward slash at starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R28BM.png)

For ref.: Installed jenkins image container details:
[Installed jenkins image container details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ban.png)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How are you running Jenkins? Are you using a docker command to run the docker image?

Comment: Yes @Atxulo, I am using 'docker start ContainerID' to start jenkins container...
Alternatively as I am using Docker Desktop so directly by clicking on play/Start button available on UI of docker desktop I can run specific image/container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to share files between the image and your host SO, [even in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10). You can do it using command line (`-v` or `--mount` command line argument) or using the docker UI.

`docker run -v /local/path/:/container/path ...`

But i'm not really sure that you can run commands inside the volume, i guess that if binaries are compatible, it should work

Comment: Thank you @Atxulo for providing the way to proceed for this issue.
I am in the process of applying the suggested process by you and will update if it works fine or not.